# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named

Tags: python, импорт, alembic

Такая проблема. Разрабатываю используя alembic

1) Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Структура папки backend

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Структура папки alembic

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В файлу env.py у меня есть импорты

```
from backend.db.db_manager import declarative_base
from backend.db_config import url
```

Когда запускаю `alembic revision --autogenerate` (эта команда по сути запускает env.py) из ROOT папки, то падает с ошибкой `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend`.

Что я делаю не так?

P.S. `__init__.py` добавлял везде, где только можно, даже в ROOT - это не помогает

P.P.S. когда добавляю над проблемными импортами `sys.path.append('.')`, все работает. Не хочу так делать, потому что это плохой способ решения проблемы. Работать должно и без этой строки. Просто, возможно, кому-то это поможет понять проблему

Comment: В какой папке запускаете утилиту? Укажите путь относительный папке проекта, или добавьте вывод команды `pwd`, если у вас unix.

Comment: @Tihon запускаю из ROOT, в которой лежит backend и alembic

Comment: Проверьте `target_metadata` в `alembic/env.py`. Там должен быть указан объект метаданных.

Comment: @Tihon а какой в этом смысл, если у меня все еще на импортах падает

Comment: Логично. Но я тогда не совсем понимаю каким образом должен помочь `sys.path.append('.')`. Он всего лишь добавляет в `PYTHONPATH` текущую рабочую директорию, в чем нет необходимости если программа запускается из корня проекта при настройках по-умолчанию... А вы случайно не создали/переопределили модуль с именем `site`?

Comment: @Tihon такого модуля у меня нет. Логика добавления append('.') как раз понятна. Интерпретатор не видит pythonpath директории с пакетам backend, я ему ее даю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108588/discussion-between-tihon-and-valentyn-anzhurov).